# Creating Multipart Line from coordinate pair lists using Geometry objects in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, python, line, geometry, multipart

I am developing a script in which I want to create a multipart line geometry.

For example:

I have one array of points a,b,c and second array of points e,d,f.

I want to create one multipart line where a,b,c defines one part and e,d,f defines the second part.

Is this possible using ArcPy?

Something like `arcpy.polyline([a,b,c], [d,e,f])` ?

Answer (score 8):

I solved it using this code:

```
arr1 = arcpy.Array([a,b,c])
arr2 = arcpy.Array([d,e,f])

resArr = arcpy.Array([arr1,arr2])

pL = arcpy.Polyline(resArr)
```